# Cased (meaning)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Perhaps, it might seem like an language question, I thought asking here would be OK.

[In this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), it says that "Return a copy of the string with all the **cased** characters [4] converted to lowercase."

What does "cased" mean in this sentence? Is the word "case" a verb in the sentence above? No meaning of the verb "case" fits in the context.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't you click the `[4]` to see what the footnote says?

> `[4]` *([1](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id6), [2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id7), [3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id8), [4](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id9))* Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the [[4]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id15) link, you'll see that

> Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).

Basically, characters that have a case. `1` doesn't, but `a` and `A` do.